# get list of older post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Is there any function that can let me display older posts and post dates at the bottom of each post?The older posts must be in the same category. I searched on the internet but it seems that everyone just display one previous post only

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The [get_posts function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) allow you to build complex queries for posts, you can use this to bring older post with the order and category parameters.

Comment: Thank Kumiau, but with get_post, how can i use operator like less/greater? i want to compare to get only post that has post_date which is smaller than the date of current post

Comment: Looks like you might need WP_Query (http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage). You can create more complex queries with this function. Search in that link: "return posts from the last 30 days". It'll show you how you can use less/greater operators in queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wp filters to achieve this

```
// Return posts from the last 30 days:
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
// posts in the last 30 days
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

OR

```
// Return posts for March 1 to March 15, 2010:
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
// posts for March 1 to March 15, 2010
$where .= " AND post_date >= '2010-03-01' AND post_date < '2010-03-16'";
return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

see this http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for more info

Comment: Thanks loQ, in the default Twenty Eleven theme, when we come into any category we can see at the bottom [Next post] and [Previous post]. If we click on these links they will display list of next/previous post. what i want is that at the bottom of a page, display list of previous posts. I think i can utilize the current load method but still don't know how to

Comment: Its link is like [http://somepage.com/category/international/europe-international/page/2/]